# Guzzle HTTP POST request in laravel

Tags: laravel

how to pass path parameter in guzzle HTTP Post request. I am having url like this - **http://base_url/v1/rack/{id}/books**

in my url **{id}** is the path parameter.

```
    $addLibraryUrl = $base_url."v1/rack/{id}/book";
    $headers["id"] = $id;
    $requestContent['json'] = $data;
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->post($addLibraryUrl, [
            "headers" => $headers,
            "json" => json_encode($data)
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you sent form params then you need to sent them as post params like :

```
// Initialize Guzzle client
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers'=> 'Some headers']);

// Create a POST request
$response = $client->request(
    'POST',
    'http://yoururl.com',
    [
        'form_params' => [
            'key1' => 'value1',
            'key2' => 'value2'
        ]
    ]
);
```

Or like in your case change 'json' to `form_params`:

```
$addLibraryUrl = $base_url."v1/rack/{id}/book";
$headers["id"] = $id;
$requestContent['json'] = $data;
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->post($addLibraryUrl, [
        "headers" => $headers,
        "form_params" => json_encode($data)
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the latest guzzle uses URI templates, but the functionality to do the parameter replacing is still there:

```
$addLibraryUrl = \GuzzleHttp\uri_template($base_url. "v1/rack/{id}/book" , [
    'id' => $id,
]);
```

Also you can just put the `id` into the URI yourself very easily.

```
$addLibraryUrl = $base_url."v1/rack/{$id}/book";
```

example:

```
blah.com/v1/rack/5/book
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue in this way:

```
    $id = your_rack_id_value;
    $client = new Client([ 'base_uri' => $base_url, ]);
    $uri = 'v1/rack/.$id.'/book';

    $requestEncodedData = json_encode($data);
    $response = $client->post($uri, [
            'body' => $requestEncodedData,
            'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ]
        ]);
```